# Lightning: How to ignore valueChange event handler from parent component if sub component 'overrides' it?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, event, lightning-apps

There are parent and sub components. Each component has :

```
<aura:handler name="change" value="{!v.var}" action="{!c.onVarChange}"/>
```

Each component defines `onVarChange` in its controller respectively. But for sub-component we have the following execution flow:

1. parent.onVarChange
2. sub.onVarChange

So both parent and sub compoents' handlers are called for sub component.

How to ignore execution of handler on parent component `parent.onVarChange` when we use sub component ?

Comment: @KrisGray you should write that up as an answer... :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want the equivalent of stopPropagation() which doesn't exist yet. Sorry. You could fake it by setting properties on the component and checking them at the different levels. Hacky but maybe your only option.